# Undefined Index

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema en PHP y me da error este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: grupo2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\siad\admin\estudiantes\agrega_estudiante.php on line 16

En el código yo tengo definida esa variable, pero sin embargo me da ese error.

Les dejo una parte del código:

```
<?php
include('../conexion.php');

$id = $_POST['id-registro'];
$proceso = $_POST['pro'];
$carnet = $_POST['carnet'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$celular = $_POST['celular'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
$grupo2 = $_POST['grupo2']; 
$carrera = $_POST['carrera'];
$foto = "images/fotos_perfil/perfil.jpg";

switch($proceso){
    case 'Registro': mysql_query("INSERT INTO estudiantes (CarnetEstudiante, NombresEstudiante, ApellidosEstudiante, CorreoEstudiante, CelularEstudiante, TelefonoEstudiante, DireccionEstudiante, Estado, Idgrupo, NombreGrupo, NombreCarrera, Foto) VALUES('$carnet','$nombre','$apellido','$correo','$celular','$telefono','$direccion','$estado','$grupo2','$grupo','$carrera','$foto')");
```

Comment: si agregas el form del cual llegan esos valores sería genial para poder ver si por ahí esta el problema

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el formulario, en tu código php estas llamando a un campo con el name de grupo2 pero no lo encuentra, así que no estás enviando ningún campo con tal nombre, talves te confundiste de nombre, no lo añadiste o simplemente lo escribiste mal dentro del form html, revisalo.

Comment: Hola, esta respuesta es más un comentario. Cuando tengas la reputación suficiente podrás comentar en todas partes. Mi sugerencia es que revises tu respuesta o incluso mejor que la elimines para no recibir reputación negativa. El OP no ha aclarado en su pregunta cómo envía la información desde el formulario y tampoco ha dado detalles sobre el formulario, sin conocer dicha información, toda respuesta estará basada en suposiciones y opiniones. Saludos